How can I get all inputs except subcommand with the Clap?
Here is my code.
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(subcommand_precedence_over_arg = true)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[arg(global = true)]
    pub input: Option<Vec<String>>,
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Option<Commands>,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Commands {
    Add,
}

If I enter following commands,
$ prog a add b

I want to get ["a", "b"] but I only get ["b"] currently.
Is it possible get all the inputs except the sub commands?

So do you want a way to collect all non-matched arguments, no matter their position?
